# is it possible to save multiple locations from user using google maps api on a single map

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps

I have an application where user can have multiple locations(max=3) , i am giving them option to locate each location on google map by searching for their place and then dragging the marker for exact location and then save their location(latitude and longitude) in database,
do i have to provide 3 different maps/views/pages for each location ,or is there a way so that a user can locate all 3 locations on a single map, like user locates  first location and then save it and then add other one and finally save all 3 locations at once.

Comment: you can have many locations on a single map

Comment: can i locate multiple locations at same time?

Comment: Yes you can do that too

Comment: can you send me a link where i can read and figure out . Thanks for help

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: studied those links but couldn't find any solution